# What is the ring $\mathbb{Z}[a]$ for a constant number $a$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I know that the notation $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is the notation for the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$, however I am confused with the notation $\mathbb{Z}[a]$ where $a$ is just a number, e.g. $a=1/3$.

Is this saying that one of the roots of the polynomials is $1/3$, i.e. $f(x)=(1-1/3)\cdot g(x)$, where $g(x)$ is in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Comment: I have submitted an edit but unfortunately I mistook in the last line so please correct it if anyone wants to accept my edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of $\Bbb Z[\alpha]$ as the evaluation of every $f\in\Bbb Z[X]$ at $\alpha$, that is, $\Bbb Z[\alpha]=\{f(\alpha)\mid f(X)\in\Bbb Z[X]\}$, even though $\alpha$ is not necessarily an element of the coefficient ring.

In your case, the elements of $\Bbb Z[1/3]$ are expressions like $a_0+\frac{a_1}3+\frac{a_2}{3^2}+\dots+\frac{a_n}{3^n}$, for some $n\in\Bbb N$.

Another example would be $\Bbb Z[\sqrt3]=\{a+b\sqrt3\mid a,b\in\Bbb Z\}$. Notice that even powers of $\sqrt3$ are integers, and odd powers are the product of an integer and $\sqrt3$, thus we only need two terms to write these expressions.
Same goes for another classic example, the Gaussian integers $\Bbb Z[i]=\{a+ib\mid a,b\in\Bbb Z\}$.

Comment: This makes sense now, thank you!

Comment: Since every integer can be expressed in base $3$, $a_0+\frac{a_1}3+\frac{a_2}{3^2}+\dots+\frac{a_n}{3^n}$ is just $\frac{b}{3^n}$ and so $\Bbb Z[1/3]$ is the set of rationals whose denominators are powers of $3$.

Comment: @lhf Yes, of course. Also, it would be appropriate to interpret these objects as subrings of some ambient ring -- as for these examples, respectively, $\Bbb{Q,R,C}$. But OP's questions seemed more just about the notation, as far as I could tell.